# Slim grab redirect html/php

Tags: php, slim

So I'm learning Slim and i've got a question...

`$app->flash` displays info before redirect

How can I get it to display `html/php` from a file. So that i can display $app->flash('global', 'Global flash'); to a file

```
$app->flash('global', 'Global flash');

return $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('document', array('id' => $id)));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you explain it with a practical  example?

Answer (score 1):

How you display the variable really depends on what Templating engine you've picked, PHP or Twig.

If it's Twig you can use this middleware to inject a `global` variable with the flash messages from `global`

```
$middleware = function(Request $request, Response $response, $next){
    $twig = $this->get('view')->getEnvironment();
    $twig->addGlobal('global', $this->get('flash')->getMessages('global'));

    return $next($request, $response);
};
$app->add($middleware);
```

If it's PHP you will have to extend `\Slim\Views\PhpRenderer` and add a static property and method to set/get globals.

But I do recommend going for the Twig templates as you'll benefit for the already existing sanitizing functionality.